# How to retrieve ambiguous columns from a hive table using subquery?

Tags: hive

## Main table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE user(language STRING,snapshot_time STRING,products STRUCT<id:STRING,name:STRING>,item STRUCT<quantity:ARRAY<STRUCT<name:STRING>>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/input/sample';
```

I'm trying to insert ambiguous column names "product.name","A.name" into user_prod_info table. Since, the column names are same, I'm facing **Ambiguous column reference text in q** error.

## Insert command:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE user_prod_info
SELECT q.* FROM (
SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY products.id ORDER BY snapshot_time DESC) AS temp_row_num,
language,
snapshot_time,
products.id,
products.name,
A.name
FROM user as raw 
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(item.quantity) quantity as A
) q WHERE temp_row_num == 1;
```

This command is unable to retrieve the field from the specific table because we have two "name" fields. one is in "products" and the other is in "A".

I tried creating alias for "A.name as name1". I'm able to insert the data without errors. But, one record is storing in 3 rows with some nulls in it.

I got stuck over here. Can anyone please help me out regarding this...

Comment: You haven't used product table at all in  after FROM .From where product table comes from?

Comment: I have edited my post by adding the main table from which I'm trying to retrieve the fields and load into my new table